# MySQL String concatenation of Title and Name

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have 2 Tables Patient table and  Title table

Patient Table 3 Fields

```
PatientTableID    FirstName PatTitleLookup 
1                  John      (Value Stored as integer)
2                  Mary      (Value Stored as integer)
```

Title Table 2 Fields

```
ID  Title
1      Mr.
2      Ms.
```

I want to concatenate Title and First Name

So I use this

```
SELECT CONCAT(`PatientTable`.`PatTitleLookup`, '. ', `PatientTable`.`FirstName`)
FROM `PatientTable`
WHERE `PatientTable`.`PatientTableID` = 1
```

I get
"1.John" instead of "Mr. John"
"2.Mary" instead of "Ms. Mary"

Please advise I am sure my syntax is wrong

Comment: Please advise how to use the join statement

Comment: I've added an answer that should be close to what you need. May need to alter table/column names if they differ.

Comment: @sam while editing please be careful about the formatting - you may edit the already formatted one.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `title`s table to get the values from it. Use an `on` for how the data should `join`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.title, '. ', pt.FirstName)
FROM PatientTable as pt
join Title as t 
on pt.PatTitleLookup = t.id
WHERE pt.PatientTableID = 1
```

I also have used aliases (`as pt`, `as t`) here for your tables, makes referencing shorter later in queries.